# How to print the symbol table of a c program in ubuntu?

Tags: c, linker, symbol-table

When compiling a C program the compiler/linker will generate a symbol table. How can we print that symbol table and what values it will store in the terminal?

Comment: Use `readelf` command. Refer [readelf utility](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/readelf.html)

Comment: The operating system doesn't generate the symbol table. It is the compiler/linker, in the object files and executables respectively.

Comment: Why have you tagged `Linux-kernel` and `operating-system` for this question?

Comment: i thought that it is related to linux-kernel

Comment: It is related to ELF format. Almost has nothing to do with kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the symbols of a compiled program or object file with `nm`(1):

```
nm a.out
```

Displays all symbols in `a.out`.